# How to guarantee that a consumable in-app purchase will be completed?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have been working with non-consumable in-app purchases until now and I'm going to use consumables in my next app.

In this new app, I have a lot of items, costing the same price, so, when the user buy one of them, I will use the same in app purchase, and save what item was bought on my server.

Here is the "problem", how can I guarantee that the transaction gonna be completed, no only in my case, but in any in-app purchase, if I have no "restore" option for this kind of IAP?

e.g: The user buys something, and right before my "unlockFeature" method the app crashes. How can I have sure that my user gonna get what he bought?

Comment: @iphonic you can't restore consumable purchases

Comment: You shouldn't call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];` until you have persisted the purchase into your server.  That way if the app crashes you will still have the transaction pending - Since you have multiple items linked to the same in-app you will need to track what was actually purchased.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes sir, my bad I realised later. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulw11 Would be a good idea if I saved a "pendingItemToPurchase" with NSDefaults, even before I start my payment process? And "clean" it when the process finishes? 
This way I can check what was going on in case that I need to restart the purchase process.